# How to make packer generated ova file work with vCenter?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, packer

I built an ova file using packer. I am using `virtualbox-iso` builder

```
source "virtualbox-iso" "test" {
.
.
.
}
```

But when I try to import the ova in `vcenter`, it gives me the following error:

> Issues detected with selected template. Details: - -1 VALUE_ILLEGAL:
> No supported hardware versions among [virtualbox-2.2]; supported:
> [vmx-04, vmx-07, vmx-08, vmx-09, vmx-10, vmx-11, vmx-12, vmx-13,
> vmx-14, vmx-15, vmx-16, vmx-17, vmx-18, vmx-19].

looks like this is a common problem. I found a few docs related to this. Most of them are talking about using external tools to fix this like OVFTOOL and then to edit the OVF XML file in the OVA package.

https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/How-to-create-a-vmware-OVA-from-a-virtualbox-ova.html

Is there any packer configuration that fixes this issue?